# Laravel Entity Attribute Value Filter Multipe Attributes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to develop a post model which has a one-to-many relationship with postmeta model (including `id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value` columns) and also has a many-to-many relationship with term model (including `term_id` and some other columns, as well as post_term table including `id`, `post_postId`, `term_term_term_id` columns).

I created a form which contains some post_metas and terms to search and to filter my posts.

This sample PHP code highlights what I used:

```php
$posts_query = Post::where('post_type', 'add')->where('author', Auth::id())->where(function ($q0) use($filter_metas){
            foreach ($filter_metas as $index => $meta) {
                $q0->whereHas('postmetas', function ($q0) use ($index,$meta) {
                    $q0->where('meta_key', $index)->where('meta_value', $meta);
                });
            }
        });
```

and this is the executed query to get results.

```sql
select * from `posts` where `post_type` = ? and `author` = ? and (exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` in (?, ?, ?, ?)) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` in (?, ?, ?)) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` > ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?) and exists (select * from `postmeta` where `posts`.`postId` = `postmeta`.`post_id` and `meta_key` = ? and `meta_value` = ?)
```

I can get correct results from this query but the query executes too slow and that is my main problem. Are there any alternative approaches?

Comment: Try not to use whereHas if you have higher number records. Add indexes if you really want to use whereHas. I faced the same issue earlier and I used joins.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, could you explain it a little bit more? Or just share an example of how doing it with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single joined query with aggregation to filter on meta attributes of each post

```
$posts = Post::select(['posts.postId','posts.name'])
            ->where('post_type', 'add')
            ->where('author', Auth::id())
            ->join('postmeta', 'posts.postId', '=', 'postmeta.post_id')
            ->groupBy('posts.postId','posts.name')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($filter_metas) {
                foreach ($filter_metas as $index => $meta) {
                    $query->havingRaw('sum(case when meta_key = ? and meta_value = ? then 1 else 0 end) > 0', [$index, $meta]);
                }
            });
```

In above query `havingRaw` part is the key it will conditionally filter out posts which don't match with the meta information,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, not sure whether it's working, hope you can get the idea.

```
        $posts_query = Post::where('post_type', 'add')
        ->where('author', Auth::id())
        ->leftJoin('postmeta', function($join){
            $join->on('posts.postId', 'postmeta.post_id');
        })
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filter_metas) {
            foreach ($filter_metas as $index => $meta) {
                $query->where('postmeta.meta_key', $index)
                    ->where('postmeta.meta_value', $meta);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this query doesn't solve my problem. When I join tables every row has one meta_key, so when i use 'and' for investigate different meta_keys there has no row that has for example meta_key=a and meta_key=b.